# How to check if Apache kafka broker connection is successful or not?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am connecting kafka producer and consumer by giving kafka broker IP port. How can I check if broker is connected successfully or not?

Comment: Can you paste your consumer and producer code here? One simple way is to use Kafka command tools: https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/kafka-console-producer-and-consumer-example/

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; grammar.

Comment: If not they will log the error messages right?

Comment: @Deadpool Yaa I know about error messages in log. But is there any tool using which i can get connection status?